# What is happening with my NestJS controller and TypeORM in this endpoint?

Tags: typescript, nestjs, typeorm

I've come across this bug that is incredibly weird, and I truly cannot figure out why it is happening.

I am trying to query for all blog post statuses (there are only three - DRAFT, PUBLISHED, and ARCHIVED) to send back to my frontend. In my controller I've defined the route as:

```
@Controller('blog/posts/statuses')
export class BlogPostStatusController {
    constructor(
        private readonly blogPostStatusService: BlogPostStatusService
    ) { }

    @Get('')
    @HttpCode(200)
    @UseGuards(JwtAuthGuard)
    async getPostStatuses(@Req() request: Request): Promise<BlogPostStatus[]> {
        const statuses = await this.blogPostStatusService.getStatuses();
        if(statuses.length === 0) throw new BlogPostStatusesWereNotFoundException();

        return statuses;
    }
}
```

The code in the service layer (using `.find()` doesn't work either):

```
@Injectable()
export class BlogPostStatusService {
    constructor(
        @InjectRepository(BlogPostStatus)
        private readonly blogPostStatusRepository: Repository<BlogPostStatus>
    ) { }

    public async getStatuses(): Promise<BlogPostStatus[]> {
        return await this.blogPostStatusRepository
            .createQueryBuilder('bps')
            .getMany();
    }
}
```

When making a request to the endpoint (`api/blog/posts/statuses`), it throws a 500 error because PostgreSQL is receiving `invalid input syntax for type integer: "statuses"`:

```
Exception thrown:  QueryFailedError: invalid input syntax for type integer: "statuses"
    at new QueryFailedError (C:\dev\repos\web\mattmaxwell\api\node_modules\typeorm\error\QueryFailedError.js:11:28)
    at Query.callback (C:\dev\repos\web\mattmaxwell\api\node_modules\typeorm\driver\postgres\PostgresQueryRunner.js:176:38)
    at Query.handleError (C:\dev\repos\web\mattmaxwell\api\node_modules\pg\lib\query.js:139:19)
    at Client._handleErrorMessage (C:\dev\repos\web\mattmaxwell\api\node_modules\pg\lib\client.js:326:17)
    at Connection.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at C:\dev\repos\web\mattmaxwell\api\node_modules\pg\lib\connection.js:109:12
    at Parser.parse (C:\dev\repos\web\mattmaxwell\api\node_modules\pg-protocol\dist\parser.js:40:17)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\dev\repos\web\mattmaxwell\api\node_modules\pg-protocol\dist\index.js:8:42)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:295:12) {
  length: 173,
  severity: 'ERROR',
  code: '22P02',
  detail: undefined,
  hint: undefined,
  position: undefined,
  internalPosition: undefined,
  internalQuery: undefined,
  where: undefined,
  schema: undefined,
  table: undefined,
  column: undefined,
  dataType: undefined,
  constraint: undefined,
  file: 'd:\\pginstaller_12.auto\\postgres.windows-x64\\src\\backend\\utils\\adt\\numutils.c',
  line: '259',
  routine: 'pg_strtoint32',
  query: 'SELECT "bp"."id" AS "bp_id", "bp"."title" AS "bp_title", "bp"."preview" AS "bp_preview", "bp"."content" AS "bp_content", "bp"."image_url" AS "bp_image_url", "bp"."created_at" AS "bp_created_at", "bp"."updated_at" AS "bp_updat
ed_at", "bp"."author_id" AS "bp_author_id", "bp"."status_id" AS "bp_status_id", "ba"."id" AS "ba_id", "ba"."first_name" AS "ba_first_name", "ba"."last_name" AS "ba_last_name", "bps"."id" AS "bps_id", "bps"."status" AS "bps_status", "bt
"."id" AS "bt_id", "bt"."name" AS "bt_name", "bt"."description" AS "bt_description", "bt"."created_at" AS "bt_created_at", "bt"."updated_at" AS "bt_updated_at" FROM "blog_post" "bp" LEFT JOIN "blog_author" "ba" ON "ba"."id"="bp"."autho
r_id"  LEFT JOIN "blog_post_status" "bps" ON "bps"."id"="bp"."status_id"  LEFT JOIN "blog_post_topics_blog_topic" "bp_bt" ON "bp_bt"."blog_post_id"="bp"."id" LEFT JOIN "blog_topic" "bt" ON "bt"."id"="bp_bt"."blog_topic_id" WHERE "bp"."
id" = $1',
  parameters: [ 'statuses' ]
}
```

As you can see, the wrong table is being queried anyway. I have NO idea why my endpoint is getting read into the query, but I noticed that if I changed the decorator to `@Get('statuses')` then the query is successful (new endpoint becomes `api/blog/posts/statuses/statuses`). Unfortunately, this is not the API endpoint I want, but for some reason it works while the other one doesn't. As of now the data is hard-coded into my frontend, which works well enough especially given that there is only three possible records, but this is a hacky solution that I do not like.

I am positive that it is not an issue with having an empty string in the decorator. Just before this I had this code inside of the controller for my posts (decorator was `@Get('statuses')` resulting in same endpoint of `api/blog/posts/statuses`), but this also threw the exact same error. I know what I am trying to do is possible because I have another entity that has different statuses (ACTIVE and INACTIVE), and querying those with an identical controller / endpoint setup works just fine. There is seemingly no reason for this to be happening, which is why I am so stumped. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

NOTE: Even changing the status controller to `@Controller('blog/statuses')` works, so I am thinking it is a problem with the endpoint itself, but... why? It seems reasonable to expect this to work, but if I am missing something then I would greatly appreciate anyone sharing some knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your answer, you probably have a controller path with something like `blog/posts/:parameter`. When you have this, no matter if you have a named route or not, if this is registered first, it will be matched first and this handler will take affect, which is probably why the query is happening with the `statuses` parameter trying to match Id, which obviously will never happen.

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION: I don't know why I didn't try this earlier, but putting my BlogPostStatusController ahead of my BlogPostController in the imports of my BlogModule allows it to work. Does anyone know why this is the case? This still doesn't explain why it didn't work whenever I had this not as a separate controller / service (although the route was defined at the very end of the controller), but... at least it works now.

Comment: Please keep to answering in an Answer. Don't ask questions in them. Kindly visit the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to see how Answers on Stack Overflow work.